# With sed or awk, how do I match from the end of the current line back to a specified character?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a list of file locations in a text file. For example:

```
/var/lib/mlocate

/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.conffiles

/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.list

/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.md5sums

/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.postinst

/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.postrm

/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.prerm
```

What I want to do is use sed or awk to read from the end of each line until the first forward slash (i.e., pick the actual file name from each file address).

I'm a bit shakey on syntax for both sed and awk. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ sed -e 's!^.*/!!' locations.txt
mlocate
mlocate.conffiles
mlocate.list
mlocate.md5sums
mlocate.postinst
mlocate.postrm
mlocate.prerm
```

Regular-expression quantifiers are greedy, which means `.*` matches as much of the input as possible. Read a pattern of the form `.*X` as "the last `X` in the string." In this case, we're deleting everything up through the final `/` in each line.

I used bangs rather than the usual forward-slash delimiters to avoid a need for escaping the literal forward slash we want to match. Otherwise, an equivalent albeit less readable command is

```
$ sed -e 's/^.*\///' locations.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Use command `basename`

```
$~hawk] basename /var/lib/mlocate
mlocate
```

Comment: basename is good for one file at a time; to process the names in a file, sed or awk works as well if not better.

Answer (score 3):

I am for "basename" too, but for the sake of completeness, here is an awk one-liner:

```
awk -F/ 'NF>0{print $NF}' <file.txt
```

Comment: for completeness get rid of the empty lines too `{if(NF>0) print $NF}` ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need to use `sed` or `awk` here, simply us `basename`

```
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(cat filelist); do
   basename $file;
done
```

If you want the directory part instead use `dirname`.

Comment: a lot a out there has spaces in file names

Comment: @ghost I added the `IFS` line. That changes the character that separates entries in that list I iterate over from space to `\n`.

Comment: +1 for $'...' syntax.  I'd never encountered that (after all these years of bashing)

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
while read -r line
do
    [[ ${#line} != 0 ]] && echo "${line##*/}"
done < files.txt
```

**Edit:** Excludes blank lines.

Comment: Cool. Any chance to squeeze a test for empty `line` into the `{}`?

Answer (score 0):

Thius would do the trick too if `file` contains the list of paths

```
 $ xargs -d '\n' -n 1 -a file basename
```

Comment: this will break on files with spaces

Comment: -d '\n' prevents breaking the line on whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

This is a less-clever, plodding version of gbacon's:

```
sed -e 's/^.*\/\([^\/]*\)$/\1/'
```

Answer (score -1):

@OP, you can use awk

```
awk -F"/" 'NF{ print $NF }' file
```

NF mean number of fields, $NF means get the value of last field

or with the shell

```
while read -r line
do
    line=${line##*/} # means longest match from the front till the "/" 
    [ ! -z  "$line" ] && echo $line
done <"file"
```

NB: if you have big files, use awk.